# How to Get The Real RecordData from DnsServerResourceRecord Using Powershell?

Tags: powershell, dns, active-directory

I'm using PowerShell to extract information from an Active Directory DNS server and I'm having trouble getting to the data I want.

Specifically, I'm trying to get the names of hosts that belong to a particular subnet, `10.104.128.x`.

When I use the following commands:

```
Get-DnsServerResourceRecord -ComputerName AD_DNS_SERVER -ZoneName 104.10.in-addr.arpa -RRType Ptr | Where-Object {$_.HostName -like '*.128'}`
```

I get output that looks like this:

```
HostName                  RecordType Timestamp            TimeToLive      RecordData                                        
--------                  ---------- ---------            ----------      ----------                                        
104.128                   PTR        10/19/2015 3:00:0... 00:15:00        adl5c260a86ba79.XYZ.net.                          
11.128                    PTR        12/29/2015 6:00:0... 00:15:00        adl3c970e8d7166.XYZ.net.                          
110.128                   PTR        1/29/2012 11:00:0... 00:15:00        nroxitow7tst.ABC.com.                       
114.128                   PTR        1/20/2012 7:00:00 AM 00:15:00        adl5c260a86c29e.ABC.com
```

What I really want are the first column, (`HostName`), which has the last two octets of the IP; and the fifth column, (`RecordData`), which has the name of the host the IP is assigned to.

The hostname is the data I really want/need.  And I see it right there!

So I used the `select` command to pare down the output in the pipe train.  New command looks like this:

```
Get-DnsServerResourceRecord -ComputerName AD_DNS_SERVER  -ZoneName 104.10.in-addr.arpa -RRType Ptr | Where-Object {$_.HostName -like '*.128'} | select HostName, RecordData
```

But the output looks like this:

```
HostName RecordData                
-------- ----------               
104.128  DnsServerResourceRecordPtr
11.128   DnsServerResourceRecordPtr
110.128  DnsServerResourceRecordPtr
114.128  DnsServerResourceRecordPtr
```

Dosen't get me the hostname though. Just the type of object the `RecordData` *is* but not the data that the object contains, perhaps?

I also tried piping the output to CSV and got the same result.

Then I tried looking at the `DnsServerResourceRecord` object properties with `Get-Member`.  That showed me the object had a property called `PSComputerName`.  I thought maybe that would have the name of the host but that came up blank when I tried to `select` it.

I then Googled around a bit and found a few pages that recommended a few ways to use RecordData.ipv4address to coax the data out of the `DnsServerResourceRecordPtr` object but I haven't gotten any of them to work yet.  Output still prints blanks.

So my question is: does a reliable method exist for getting the actual hostname from a PTR record?

Comment: RecordData  is an object with its own properties. Save the results of your first query then run Get-Member against record data. `$result.RecordData | get-member`. Then you will see the properties you want. A calculated expression with merge that with the other properties. Have a look here for example: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/e5179679-e766-45d9-966d-dc2f0bf2d24b/how-to-find-all-properties-of-recorddata-from-getdnsserverresourcerecord?forum=ITCG

Comment: That helped alot!  I assigned the output of the command to a variable, `$result`.  Using `get-member` showed me the `PtrDomainName` property which then led me to `$result.RecordData.PtrDomainName` which prints the actual names of the computers.  Now I need to figure out how to print the hostname (the two octets, in the case of this object) along with the PtrDomainName.  @Matt if you would like to add your comment and as answer, I will gladly accept it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To select the `PtrDomainName` property from the `DnsServerResourceRecordPtr` object, use a calculated property:

```
... |Select-Object HostName, @{Name='RecordData';Expression={$_.RecordData.PtrDomainName}}
```

Comment: That worked perfectly.  Thanks.  `Get-DnsServerResourceRecord -ComputerName AD_DNS_SERVER -ZoneName 104.10.in-addr.arpa -RRType Ptr | Where-Object {$_.HostName -like '*.128'} | select HostName, RecordData`

Answer (score 3):

Yes it's really weird that you can't just call ToString on the DNS record data, it's all formatted using the PowerShell formatters which you can only access with Format-List or Format-Table, rather than just calling $resourceRecord.RecordData.ToString().

I've added more data types than Krzysztof Madej by just hacking out the PowerShell formatters from the XML file, the details are here.
http://david-homer.blogspot.com/2020/10/getting-text-representation-of.html

Answer (score 2):

```bsh
$dnsserver = "yourowndnsserver"
$dnszones = Get-DnsServerZone -ComputerName $dnsserver | Select-Object ZoneName 

ForEach ($zone in $dnszones) {
    $data = New-Object System.Object 
    $ZoneName = $zone.ZoneName 
    $data = Get-DnsServerResourceRecord $ZoneName -ComputerName $dnsserver
    foreach ($registros in $data) {
        $data = $ZoneName
        $data += ","
        $data += $registros.hostname;
        $data += ","
        $data += $RecordType = $registros.recordType;
        $data += ","
        
        if ($RecordType -like "PTR") {
            $data += $registros.RecordData.PtrDomainName
        }
        elseif ($RecordType -like "A") {
            $data += $([system.version]($registros.RecordData.ipv4address.IPAddressToString));
        }
        elseif ($RecordType -like "CNAME") {
            $data += $registros.RecordData.HostNameAlias;
        }
        elseif ($RecordType -like "NS") {
            $data += $registros.RecordData.nameserver;
        }
        elseif ($RecordType -like "MX") {
            $data += $registros.RecordData.MailExchange;
        }
        elseif ($RecordType -like "SOA") {
            $data += $registros.RecordData.PrimaryServer;
        }
        elseif ($RecordType -like "SRV") {
            $data += $registros.RecordData.DomainName;
        }
        $data | out-file -FilePath $env:TEMP\$(Get-Date -Format dd_MM_yyyy)_DNSRecords.csv -Append
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Since you spent so many hours, please take some extra minutes and explain your answer, explain why it is better than the existing answers too (if possible)